# Orchard: In what table is the Blog post stored

Tags: orchardcms

I'm attempting to export data from an older Orchard db and am having problems finding which table the content of a blog post is stored. I've tried using a number of different 'Search all columns' spocs to search all tables and columns but am not finding text from the post itself.

If I have a blog post where the opening sentence is:
This sentence contains a unique word.

I would have expected at least one of the various 'Search all columns' examples to have turned up a table/column. But so far, none have.

thx

Comment: Please note that the deleted answer, which was recommending using the export feature, actually was the correct one. Querying the database in Orchard directly in SQL is highly discouraged. Searching for terms in content items is also not a suitable job for SQL: Orchard includes Lucene search, which is what should be used for such full-text searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Orchard store data based on two tables, `ContentItemRecord` and `ContentItemVersionRecord`, which store meta data for content items like `BlogPost`, and these content items built from multiple parts, each part has it's table and the relation between the item and it's parts is based on `Id` (if not draftable) or `ContentItemRecord_Id` (if draftable) columns

if we take `BlogPost` type as example, which built from `TitlePart`, `BodyPart`, `AutoroutePart` and `CommonPart`, and you want to select all the data of post (id = 90), then you can find it's title in `TitlePartRecord` table (`ContentItemRecord_Id = 90`), and the body text of it in `BodyPartRecord` table with same relation as title part record, and the route part in `AutorouteRecord` table with same relation, and the common meta data in `CommonPartRecord` (Id = 90).

This is the way to extract data from Orchard database, hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Tnx to @mdameer...
and the related query of madmeer's answer is this:

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.default_Title_TitlePartRecord 
 inner join dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord on 
 dbo.default_Title_TitlePartRecord.ContentItemRecord_id=dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id 
 inner join dbo.default_Common_BodyPartRecord on 
 dbo.default_Common_BodyPartRecord.ContentItemRecord_id=dbo.default_Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.Id
 where dbo.default_Title_TitlePartRecord.ContentItemRecord_id=90
```

and this is the rightsolution

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it may be useful for others, the following is the actual SQL query used to migrate an Orchard instance to Umbraco.  It is derived from the excellent answers by mdameerand and Iman Salehi:

```
SELECT t.Title, f.Data, b.Text  FROM dbo.Title_TitlePartRecord t
 inner join dbo.Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord f on 
 t.ContentItemRecord_id=f.Id 
  inner join dbo.Common_BodyPartRecord b on 
 b.ContentItemRecord_id=f.Id
  AND  b.Id = (
            SELECT MAX(m2.Id) 
            FROM dbo.Common_BodyPartRecord m2 
            WHERE m2.ContentItemRecord_id = f.Id
        )
  AND  t.Id = (
            SELECT MAX(m2.Id) 
            FROM dbo.Title_TitlePartRecord m2 
            WHERE m2.ContentItemRecord_id = f.Id
        )
```